# Minimizing *similar* pairs of nodes in a non-weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, nodes, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to reduce this [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12770/find-the-composite-poison-in-the-wine-bottles/13149) into a programming one. I've let each prisoner represent a color and each bottle is a node. As long as there is no *similar* pair (see below), it is possible to pinpoint the poisoned bottles (on day 1).

> We have $1000$ nodes. You must connect them using different color
>   bands, and you have a total of $n$ colours. There cannot exist 2
>   independent networks of the same color.
>
> If Node A is connected using a red band to Node B, and Node B is
>   connected to Node C using another red band, Node A and Node C are also
>   said to be connected via a red band. Therefore, A, B and C belong to
>   the red network.
>
> Two pairs of nodes are said to be *similar* if they are connected by
>   the same color bands (no more, no less). For example, if A and B are
>   connected via the red, green and violet networks (but no other
>   network), and if C and D are connected via the red, green and violet
>   networks (but no other network), AB and CD are a *similar* pair.
>   A similar pair may share a node, so AB and AC could forma valid 
>   similar pair.
>
> For a given value of $n$, what is the minimum number of *similar*
>   pairs possible? Solve using an algorithm (or mathematical function,
>   if possible).

P. S.

1. Please don't close this as a H.W. question, it is not one. I know very little about algorithms, so I'm more interested in just the final program, rather than its functioning.
2. It is not only for me, there are a lot of people at Puzzling SE who would want this answered.

Comment: maybe post this as a [golf question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yeah, that happened last time we came across a problem with similar algorithmic difficulties too.

Comment: @lloydm I was going to, but they said it was only for contests and challenges. I was not sure if it was on-topic. And besides, I'm not sure if it is a good idea to have a duplicate now.

Comment: Your objective winning criterion would be the algorithm that manages to differentiate between the most bottles for 20 prisoners.

Comment: That was the limit that I put in the "alternative" answer to the original question. As it is, you're going to get a lot of answers that have 18, 19, or 20 prisoners, and a 4-digit number is easier to differentiate solutions between.

Comment: @JoeZ. Maybe. I was actually trying to see if the original answer could be better than 18. For example, for n=17, if we know the number of combinations to check on day 2, we can know if it is possible or not. This would prove the optimal solution (or improve it).

Comment: Is this the opposite of the [Four Color Theorem](http://nrich.maths.org/6291). Faces Edges Vertices, and you're looking for loops?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code: I made it into a [code golf problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50396/build-a-poisoned-wine-testing-scheduler) for you.

Comment: This is the kind of large, highly symmetric problem that terrorizes mathematical optimization algorithms. I wouldn't expect much.